# Outputting numbers symbolically

Tags: output-formatting

Suppose I want Mathematica to output

```
Table[2^n, {n, 1, 5}]
```

Mathematica gives

```
{2, 4, 8, 16, 32}
```

but how can I get Mathematica to output

```
{2, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 2^5}
```

?

**EDIT**

What about more complicated expressions like:

```
Table[n^2, {n, 1, 5}]
```

Mathematica gives

```
{1, 4, 9, 16, 25}.
```

If I try

```
Table[HoldForm@n^2, {n, 1, 5}]
```

I get the unexpected (to me)

```
{n^2, n^2, n^2, n^2, n^2}
```

Comment: `Table[HoldForm@2^n, {n, 1, 5}]`  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qmkmo.png)

Comment: `Inactivate[Table[2^n, {n, 1, 5}], Power]` (I am not obsessed with Inactive I promise)

Comment: @chuy That's an elegant answer - much more than a comment.

Comment: To output `Table[2^n, {n, 1, 5}]` simply type "Table[2^n, {n, 1, 5}]"  and hit <shift>+<return>

Comment: Thank you @ Nasser, @ chuy, @ David Carraher, @kguler. Your comments and answers have helped me a lot, and I was **not** able to find the answer contrary to the "closers". Looking through the Help files did not help me in the slightest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Table[x^n, {n, 1, 5}] /. x -> "2"
```

Comment: I like this way indeed - much simpler for me than `HoldForm`, and I can do things like:

    `Table[x^n*n^y, {n, 1, 5}] /. {x -> "2", y -> "3"}`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Table[With[{n = n}, HoldForm[2^n]], {n, 1, 5}]
(* or Table[With[{n = n}, Defer[2^n]], {n, 1, 5}] *)
```

[image]

```
Table[With[{n = n}, HoldForm@n^2], {n, 1, 5}]
(* or Table[With[{n = n}, Defer@n^2], {n, 1, 5}] *)
```

[image]

Update: If `1` and `1^2` (similarly, `2` and `2^1`) are both acceptable, then you can use a simpler variant of Alexey's answer without the need for `ReplaceAll`:

```
{Array["2"^# &, {5}], Array[#^"2" &, {5}]}
```

[image]

or

```
{Table["2"^n, {n, 1, 5}], Table[n^"2", {n, 1, 5}]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Nasser suggested, the following works for the first part of the post:

```
Table[HoldForm@2^n, {n, 1, 5}]
```

I found the answer for **EDIT1:** to be:

```
Table[(HoldForm[2^#1] &)[i], {i, 1, 5}]
```

Comment: You might find `Table[(Defer[2^#1] &)[i], {i, 1, 5}]` sometimes more suitable.  If you copy and paste it, it can be evaluated without using `ReleaseHold`.